# How build dynamic query elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I would like to build a query to elasticsearch using search criteria from a html form. I have several input fields on the html page. For example, if the user fill two of these fields I could write :

```
    BoolQueryBuilder query =  QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                                .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("archivo", "archivo1"))
                                .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("nombre", "documento1"));
```

But... what if the user fill three fields I could have :

```
    BoolQueryBuilder query =  QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                        .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("archivo", "archivo1"))
                        .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("nombre", "documento1"))
                        .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("third", "test"));
```

Is there any way to dinamicall build this kind of queries?

Answer (score 9):

`BoolQueryBuilder.must()` adds a predicate, it does not replace the previous one.

Therefore, suppose that the value of the field `archivo` is in the variable `inputArchivo` and so on, you can check if the field is filled then add the predicate :

```
 BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
 if(inputArchivo != null && !inputArchivo.isEmpty()) {
   query.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("archivo", inputArchivo));
 }

 if(inputNombre != null && !inputNombre.isEmpty()) {
   query.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("nombre", inputNombre));
 }

 if(inputThird != null && !inputThird.isEmpty()) {
   query.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("third", inputThird));
 }
```

and yet if you don't know what terms will came you can iterate over a HashMap with the values:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    query.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery(entry.getKey, entry.getValue))
}
```